Can I refer to one TypeVar in the bound of another TypeVar?
I have a generic Base class that instantiates a class called Factory. The Factory class is provided to Base by Base's subclasses, and then Base passes the instance to certain subclass methods.
I want the type of Factory in Base to depend upon an earlier TypeVar. Is there a way to express this in Python?
Generic for TypeVar and Iterator (or another generic) of that TypeVar (from a few years ago) says, "no". Has that changed? If not, is there an alternative way to get the types I'm after (maybe involving Protocol)?
I tried this:
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Factory(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, session: Session) -> None:
        self.session = session
    
    def get(self, id: int) -> T | None:
        return None

    def all(self) -> list[T]:
        return []

class Session:
    def query(self, query: object) -> object:
        pass
    
F = TypeVar("F", bound=Factory[T])

class Base(Generic[T, F]):
    def __init__(self, Factory: type[F]) -> None:
        self.Factory = Factory

    def doSomething(self, factory: F, thing: T) -> None:
        pass

    def run(self, session: Session) -> None:
        factory = self.Factory(session)
        for thing in factory.all():
            self.doSomething(factory, thing)

class User:
    userId: int
    name: str

class UserFactory(Factory[User]):
    def login(self, user: User) -> None:
        self.session.query('whatever')

class UserThing(Base[User, UserFactory]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(UserFactory)

    def doSomething(self, factory: UserFactory, user: User) -> None:
        factory.login(user)

and get the errors
main.py:19: error: Type variable "__main__.T" is unbound  [valid-type]
main.py:19: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)
main.py:19: note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

I'm more familiar with TypeScript, where I was able to express the idea I'm after:
class Factory<T> {
    constructor(protected session: Session) {}
    get(id: number): T | null {
        return null
    }
    all(): T[] {
        return []
    }
}

interface Session {
    query(query: unknown): unknown
}

abstract class Base<T, F extends Factory<T>> {
    constructor(public readonly Factory: { new (session:Session): F }) {
    }

    abstract doSomething(factory: F, thing: T): void

    public run(session: Session) {
        const factory = new this.Factory(session)
        for (const thing of factory.all()) {
            this.doSomething(factory, thing)
        }
    }
}

interface User {
    userId: number
    name: string
}

class UserFactory extends Factory<User> {
    login(user: User) {
        this.session.query('whatever')
    }
}

class UserThing extends Base<User, UserFactory> {
    constructor() {
        super(UserFactory)
    }
    doSomething(factory: UserFactory, user: User) {
        factory.login(user)
    }
}


"Has that changed?": Unfortunately, no, and that might not happen for another 2 years.
